# Number stored as text warning in excel using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting `Number stored as text warning` for the created excel file using **POI**. I am trying to display percentage. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939273/ho-can-i-remove-the-green-arrow-from-a-cell-on-excel-file-using-python-xlsxwrite) discusses the same, but it's for python. Can some one please suggest me how to avoid this in java using POI?

Below are the lines where I get this warning.

```
workbook= new XSSFWorkbook();
sh1 = wb.createSheet("Data Sheet");
    cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue(37 + "%");
```

Based on Gagravarr answer I did it this way.

```
XSSFDataFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
                    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
                    cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("%"));
                    cell.setCellValue(0.37);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

But it just shows up as 0.37 with no warning now, not 37%.

Comment: The warning is genuine... you are using 37 as number and appending % that is not possible as a number cannot be added with a character. instead if you use "37" instead of 37, it will not give any error.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh Well, afaik concatinating the number to a string converts the entire thing to String. Then even after setting the whole thing as string, it throws such error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're getting the warning because, as it says, you're storing a number as text.

What you probably want to do is:

```
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("%"));
cell.setCellValue(0.37);
cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

That will store the number 37 as a number, and tell excel to apply a percentage format string to it. Oh, and since 37% is 0.37, you need to store 0.37 not 37!

**Edit** By popular request, here's a standalone program you can use to see it in action, for both .xls and .xlsx files. Tested with POI 3.10 final, and with [all the required dependencies and component jars](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on the classpath.

```
public class TestPercent {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Generating...");

    for (Workbook wb : new Workbook[] {new HSSFWorkbook(), new XSSFWorkbook()}) {
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Data Sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(3);

        DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("%"));
        cell.setCellValue(0.37);
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);

        String output = "/tmp/text.xls";
        if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) { output += "x"; }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output);
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. Please check my edited question based on your answer.

Comment: I've just tried this very code with POI 3.10 final, opened the resulting file, and it rendered as "37%" exactly as expected!

Comment: +1 for your answer. Can you please check my edited question whether it is different from what you tried? or can you please show the full code what you have done?

Comment: I've posted a standalone program which I used to test, does both .xls and .xlsx

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I am accepting your answer. But I don't know where it goes wrong in my case. I even copied your entire code and created a new one and tested. It now shows only "%" symbol and not the number. When I clicked on the particular cell, the value is shown as 0.37 in the fx space above the sheet.

Comment: Are you sure you're using POI 3.10 final? And you really don't have any older POI jars on your classpath?

Answer (score 5):

Try also setting the CellType:

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(NumberUtils.isDigits(text)){
        titleCell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(text));
    }else{
        titleCell.setCellValue(text);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. You can also use `Double.parseDouble(text)` instead of Int

Answer (score 2):

As already explained by existing answers, you get that warning if you write a number as text by mistake; however in some cases it is not a mistake: a "product code", for example, could be a *numeric string*, i.e. a string containing only digits (possibly with leading zeros).  In this case the solution is to **disable that warning**:

```java
if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    XSSFSheet xsheet = (XSSFSheet)sheet;
    xsheet.addIgnoredErrors(new CellRangeAddress(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 0, 20),
            IgnoredErrorType.NUMBER_STORED_AS_TEXT);
}
```

The cell range could be a specific "code" column or all populated columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
    XSSFWorkbook xSSFWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = xSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFCellStyle numberStyle = xSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle();             
    numberStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("###.00"));
    double d = 50.0;
    XSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cellcel1 = dataRow.createCell(1);
    cel1.setCellValue(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit old but try this:

```
df.getFormat("0.00%")
```